# How to see closed bugs in Microsoft test manager

Tags: testing, microsoft-test-manager

I could not see the closed bugs in Microsoft test manager. 
It showing only active bugs.In the filter also other state of bug is not listing to select . 
So is there any option to manage filter in verify bugs tab,

Comment: Why would you like to verify closed bug? Regression testing?

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the default filters to reflect your desire:

1- Open Microsoft Test Manager -> Test -> Verify Bugs

2- Select the view -> Filter -> Edit (filter name)

3- Change the clauses to add "Closed Bugs"